# Checking for a bootstrap dropdown Value in Selenium Webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I have a dropdown menu as below and I want to check if a particular value is present in that dropdown menu by using Java Selenium Web driver.

I need to check if Value 3 is present in dropdown menu. Below is the HTML snippet.

Can someone help me to  understand how this can be achieved?

```
<div id="select2-drop">
<ul class="select2-results">
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
        <div class="select2-result-label">
            <span class="select2-match"></span>
            Value 1
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
        <div class="select2-result-label">
            <span class="select2-match"></span>
            Value 2
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
        <div class="select2-result-label">
            <span class="select2-match"></span>
            Value 3
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted">
        <div class="select2-result-label">
            <span class="select2-match"></span>
            Value 4
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using is [Select2 3.x](http://select2.github.io/select2/) Dropdown.

The problem is you have to click on the select. Then only the list is added to the DOM[The list will be visible]

You can use this xpath to check the availability of option

```
//div[@class='select2-result-label'][text()='optionText']
```

But before that you have to click on the select container.Most probably it will be of

```
 //div[contains(@class,'select2-container')]
```

Sample code I've automated on the Example page

```
 driver.get("http://select2.github.io/select2/");
    WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'select2-container')]"));
    select.click();
    String optionText="Alaska";
    List<WebElement> options=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='select2-result-label'][text()='"+optionText+"']"));
    if(options.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("Option not present");
    else
        System.out.println("Present");
```